# BigQuery save OPTIONS(strict_mode=FALSE) in procedure

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have procedure below which create procedure in different projects

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `sp_get_data`(arg_ProjectID STRING, arg_DatasetID STRING)
OPTIONS(strict_mode=FALSE)
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `"|| arg_ProjectID || "." || arg_DatasetID || ".sp_get_data_details`()                                             \r\n"||
        "BEGIN 
    -- lengthy code
    "END"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        ;       
    END;
```

The code insde procedure is very very lengthy.

When I run this create procedure with **OPTIONS(strict_mode=FALSE)**, it is working..., but it doesn't not save in procedure script..
how to make it persist in procedure script

without it throws error

> Query error: Out of stack space due to deeply nested query expression
> during query resolutio

But how can I add this dynamically when calling like

**call sp_get_data(projectid,datasetid)**

Any help,
Highly appreciated

Comment: I replace it to `"BEGIN "|| "END" ` then with `OPTIONS(strict_mode=FALSE)` the both procedures were created. Also if I comment out the option line it worked.